# Win Server Kerberos Etype Issue

Tags: kerberos, windows-server

after having installed recent WUs, I am unable to log on to the servers.
I see event id 40970 lsa downgrade attempt 0xc00002fd and also event id 14 from the KDC.
There, it tells me that the requested Kerberos Etype was 18 3 and that the available Etype is 23 18 17.

So it is clear why the logon attempt failed but I do not know how to fix it. The following was checked:

- Checked GPO that the local sec pol has future enc types and AES 256 enabled
- Checked User Account that AES 256 is enabled
- Checked computer accounts of DC and client server that AES 256 is enabled
- Checked RSOP on client machine that AES 256 is applied.
- Changed pwd of affected user account

The first 4 were already correct, the changed pwd did not help.
I created a new AD account with domain admin rights and tried to logon with that one but it also failed due to the same issue.

On the DC that was not updated, i still can logon with the same account so clearly it is related to the Nov Updates. Not sure if this one could have anything to do with it: [MS](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/topic/kb5021131-how-to-manage-the-kerberos-protocol-changes-related-to-cve-2022-37966-fd837ac3-cdec-4e76-a6ec-86e67501407d)

Any idea what else I could do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems indeed to be related to the update.
[Link](https://borncity.com/win/2022/11/10/updates-for-windows-nov-2022-changes-in-netlogon-and-kerberos-protocol-causing-issues/)

What worked for me as a workaround is to allow the RC4 Etype for all DCs and Clients. Hopefully, MS will fix that asap because instead of increasing the security, they now lowered it...